# Always show decimal places in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting

I'm working on a query which returns numeric values (currency).  Some of the values are whole numbers and are being displayed as 3, 5, 2 etc whilst other numbers are coming up like 2.52, 4.50 etc.

How can I force oracle to always show the decimal places?

Thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
TO_CHAR(pAmount, '9,999,999.99');
```

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_char.php

http://www.ss64.com/orasyntax/to_char.html

Comment: Thanks.  Can this also be used to add zeros to numbers that are less than 1? eg 0.52 instead of .52?

Comment: From the top of my head use TO_CHAR(pAmount, '9,999,990.99');

Answer (score 14):

To enhance the answers already given, you can use:

- `TO_CHAR(your_value,'fm999.99')` to prevent leading spaces

  `____3.45` becomes `3.45` (`_` indicates whitespace)
- `TO_CHAR(your_value,'fm990.99')` to force values less than `1` to show a leading zero

  `.52` becomes `0.52`
- `TO_CHAR(your_value,'fm990.00')` to force 2 decimal places, even if `0`

  `6.3` becomes `6.30`
- `(TO_CHAR(your_value,'fm990.00')||'%')` to add a percentage sign

  `18.6` becomes `18.60%`

source: https://community.oracle.com/thread/968373?start=0&tstart=0

Answer (score 3):

The display and formatting of the data should be handled at the presentation layer - not the data one.

Use the facilities provided by your front end to format the values as you see fit.

Comment: What if Oracle *is* the presentation layer?  e.g. the MODPLSQL toolkit?

Comment: or a simple report in SQL*Plus?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus you can use the COLUMN directive to specify formatting on a per-column basis, separate from the query itself. That way you keep your query "clean" for possible other uses and still get your formatting. (In SQL*Plus at least...)

e.g

```
COLUMN SAL FORMAT 99,990.99
```

Google for "SQL*Plus User's Guide and Reference" and you should get links to the Oracle location for your Oracle version. 10.1 is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/toc.htm) if that'll do. They'll probably all be about the same, mind you: I don't think SQL*Plus has changed much since I learned it in 1988 on Oracle 5.1.17...

Answer (score 1):

The `to_char` fixes the decimal issue but you have to be certain about the length. If it is longer than the format provided, it will show the number as `####`. If the number is shorter, then it will leave spaces before the number. e.g

`to_char(123.45),'99.00')` will show `####`

and

`to_char(123.45),'999999.00')` will show `'   123.45'`.

So, if you have to export the results to CSV or Excel, these numbers will be treated as string.

So, I have not found any solution to it.

Comment: using the `fm` instruction at the start of the formatting will remove the extra spaces

Comment: The solution has been listed below: TO_CHAR(your_value,'fm990.00'), forces 2 decimal places and omits leading whitespace