# How do I set the number of digits from results of aggregate SUM()?

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle, I am trying to obtain the sum of sales, which are of the type DECIMAL(5,2). I also want the SUM'd column to return with 2 decimal places.

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT I.upc, category, sellPrice, total, sum(TOTAL*sellPrice)"TOTALVALUE"
...
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (I.upc, category, sellPrice, TOTAL), (category), ());
```

An example of the table I receive from the query is:

```
UPC   CATEGORY  SELLPRICE TOTAL TOTALVALUE
--- ----------  --------- ----- ----------
  0    Fantasy      20.99     2      41.98
  1    Fantasy      30.99     5     154.95
       Fantasy                      196.93
  2  Classical      10.99     3      32.97
     Classical                       32.97
                                     229.9
```

Note that the last value at the bottom right, the grand total, is set with 1 decimal place.

I have tried to cast the sum as a DECIMAL(5,2) type, but to no avail. Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pls don't post tab delimited code/etc - it really screws with the formatting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Always show decimal places in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799151/always-show-decimal-places-in-sql)

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the tables look nice from my end. I will fix that up. Thanks for the link, I will take a look.

Comment: @danny-london: I just tried that, no luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
to_char(sum(TOTAL*sellPrice), 'FM99999990D00')
```

The FM removes leading blanks.
The 9's represent an optional number in that position.
The D represents the decimal separator.
The 0's represent mandatory numbers in that position.

This ensures that all number have at least two decimals.

[Read more about Oracle format models](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210).

Answer (score 2):

Use `TO_CHAR` with [format specifier](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-numfmt.html) `99999D99` for example?

Your problem here is that the last digit would be a zero.

Comment: I'll give it a shot in the morning, if all else fails.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this seems to just be a matter of display.  If you case to 5,2, it will be 5,2.  What matters is how you display it later on.  Just because your tool is not showing the last zero, does not mean it is not there.

Comment: True, its just one of those little things that bug me. I thought that there would be a way to display my data the way I wanted it to display.