# Oracle SQL display 2 decimaldigits

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I display 2 decimal digits for an integer? The column I wish to display contains both int and float

For example:
3000 display as 3000.00;
235.5 display as 235.50;
123.126 dispaly as 123.12

Comment: That is not a task to be dealt with by a database.

Comment: As @Luuk said a database should not be concerned with the presentation of data. If you have a need for it nevertheless take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799151/always-show-decimal-places-in-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `to_char` function with desired format mask. For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 3000    from dual union all
  3     select 235.5   from dual union all
  4     select 123.126 from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         to_char(col, '999g999g990d00') result
  8  from test;

       COL RESULT
---------- ---------------
      3000        3.000,00
     235,5          235,50
   123,126          123,13

SQL>
```

---

Another is to use `set numformat`:

```
SQL> set numformat 999g999g990d00
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 3000   from dual union all
  3     select 235.5  from dual union all
  4     select 123.126 from dual
  5    )
  6  select col
  7  from test;

            COL
---------------
       3.000,00
         235,50
         123,13

SQL>
```

(In SQL Developer you might need to use e.g. `set numformat 999,999,990.00` because previously suggested option might raise `SP2-0246: illegal FORMAT string` error).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this with rounding:

```
SELECT 
-- Remove leading & trailing whitespaces and zeroes + format + round
TO_CHAR(ROUND(your_column, 2), 'FM999999990.00') AS rounded_formatted_column
FROM your_table;
```

Or without rounding:

```
SELECT 
-- Remove leading & trailing whitespaces and zeroes + format
TO_CHAR(your_column, 'FM999999990.00') AS formatted_column
FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `TO_CHAR` function with a custom format mask.

**example**

```
SELECT TO_CHAR("column_name", '9999999990.00') AS formatted_number FROM "table_name";
```